# Multiple Session executing Snowflake Procedure Insert into same Table

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a snowflake procedure that insert record into a table, something similar to below procedure. When this procedure is called by multiple application in multiple session, it is behaving erratic and throwing error. I understand when multiple session is trying to write to same table it is throwing error. Is there any work around to handle this scenario, since we do want to duplicate this proc for every application. Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SP_CRT_METADATA"(SOURCE_TYPE VARCHAR, BATCH_ID FLOAT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216)
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS '

hist_col_load =` INSERT INTO SHRD_COL_MSTR_HIST SELECT * FROM SHRD_COL_MSTR WHERE SRC_TYPE =''`+SOURCE_TYPE+`''  AND ACTIVE_IND =''Y''`;

snowflake.execute({sqlText: hist_col_load});

'
```

Comment: "behaving erratic and throwing error" can you be more specific? what's the error? what's the erratic behavior?

Comment: @Felipe  Its throws some random error each time.

Comment: Nevertheless including error messages will be helpful

Comment: I'll vote to close this question, until you can give us the exact error messages @gopinathkolanchi. Even if they are random, having the exact message makes a world of difference when trying to debug

Comment: @demircioglu - When i execute THE PROC 3 TIMES IN PARALLEL SP_CRT_METADATA('AUTOPLCY',1) , call SP_CRT_METADATA('HOPLCY',1), call SP_CRT_METADATA('PLCY',1) - 2 of them getting successful and 1 execution getting failed with the below error.-   error code is 100183-SQL compilation error: Object SHRD_COL_MSTR_HIST does not exist or not authorized.-At Snowflake.execute, line 312 position 11 - Statement

Comment: This looks like a permission issue, please update the question with the error message rather than including in a comment.

Comment: @demircioglu - No this is not a permission, 2 proc is getting completed and one proc is failing, this is due to concurrent execution issue. I would like to know how to solve the concurrent execution.